# Nuget Source Authentification 401 Authentification

Tags: command-line, nuget, manage-nuget-packages

I want to use the command `"dotnet list ${pathToCsproj} package --interactive --outdated --source ${privateSource}"`

But I get this error:
Die folgenden Quellen wurden verwendet:
https://nuget....company/index.json

warn : Your request could not be authenticated by the GitHub Packages service. Please ensure your access token is valid and has the appropriate scopes configured.warn : Your request could not be authenticated by the GitHub Packages service. Please ensure your access token is valid and has the appropriate scopes configured.error: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).

Usage: NuGet.CommandLine.XPlat.dll package list [arguments] [options]

Arguments:
<PROJECT | SOLUTION>  Ein Pfad zu einem Projekt, einer Projektmappendatei oder einem Verzeichnis.

Options:

-h|--help
--force-english-output
--framework
--deprecated
--outdated
--vulnerable
--include-transitive
--include-prerelease
--highest-patch
--highest-minor
--source
--config
--interactive
-v|--verbosity

I have already read posts like [Unable to access NuGet sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54970381/unable-to-access-nuget-sources), https://github.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider, https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7605, or https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/issues/69 but either I do not understand them and/or don't know how to apply the tips and suggestions in these posts.

What do I have to do exacty to make it work?
How exactly can I authenticate within this command?
Do I have to download a package to authenticate?

Please help me.

Comment: GitHub has docs explaining how to authenticate: https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-nuget-registry#authenticating-with-a-personal-access-token